# Obtaining $B$-module from $A$-module via surjective ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose I have a surjective ring homomorphism $\varphi\colon A\rightarrow B$. Then if I have an $A$-module $M$, is there a way for me to define a $B$-module, naturally? It seems like the constraint on $M$ I need is that all $a\in\ker\varphi$ to act as $am=0$ for all $m\in M$. Then, I think it would make sense to define the action of $bm=am$ where $b=\varphi(a)$; the kernel acting trivially makes this action well-defined.

Is this the only way to do it? Or can it be done with any $A$-module?

Comment: What you are saying is correct; you need $\ker \varphi$ to act trivially for this to be well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to use the map $\varphi$ to define a $B-$module structure on $M$, the only really sensible way to do this is as you say. Of course, you could try to define
$$b\cdot m=(na)\cdot m$$
or something like this, with $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ and $a\in \varphi^{-1}(b)$. This wouldn't really do anything for you, though as this is asking the same question for $\varphi:A\to B$ except now $M$ has a different $A-$module structure.

This being said, it is necessary and sufficient that $\ker \varphi$ act as zero on $M$. Indeed, if $b=\varphi(a)$ and $b=\varphi(a')$, then $b\cdot m$ defined as above is well-defined if and only if $a\cdot m =a'\cdot m$ if and only if $(a-a')\cdot m=0$.